# Need to deploy node.js+ mongoDB app on heroku, but they are asking for credit card for installing add on

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, deployment

I need to deploy my app on heroku, but when try to install mongoDB they want me to enter the credit card details, is there any way to get around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way around giving a credit card when using deploying a database (or using most add-ons).

But just because you provide a credit card, does not mean that Heroku will charge you anything. In general if this is a personal app, that you aren't using often, you will never exceed the 1,000 free dyno hours per month.

I am in a coding bootcamp, where we make and deploy a new app each week, and I have never even come close to 10% of that. Granted, its really only me and instructors using the apps, so please take that with a grain of salt. But I would assume if you are making a widely used app, then you probably would need to pay for more dyno hours regardless.

Please refer to the following for more info...
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hour-faq